Why isn't my static FIL reference updating when assigned to another static FIL variable?
I have three FIL variables in my program which are local to a single file (sd_card.c):
static FIL mainFileRef;
static FIL fileA;
static FIL fileB;

Depending on the mode selected, the file should write into one of two files: fileA or fileB. And mainFileRef file acts as the main reference to the file being used.
For some reason which I am probably missing, when I try to assign mainFileRef to either fileA or fileB, mainFileRef's address does not change. I have confirmed this on a memory level in debug mode.
static FIL mainFileRef;     // memory address 0x1FFF8AA0
static FIL fileA;           // memory address 0x1FFF8CE4
static FIL fileB;           // memory address 0x1FFF8F08

mode = 0;

void assignFile(){
    if(mode == 0){
        mainFileRef = fileA;        // results = mainFileRef keeping its 8AA0 
    }
    else if(mode == 1){
        mainFileRef = fileB;
    }    
}

My expectation is that mainFileRef's address will equal the address of either fileA or fileB if assigned.
I tried setting mainFileRef as a pointer, and assigning the address of fileA to it, but that gave me the same result:
FIL *mainFileRef;

mainFileRef = &fileA;

What's going on here, why, and how can I avoid this in the future? I feel like I am missing something very simple here...

What is FIL ?

@wohlstad embedded library for SD card writing. it's a file pointer for a FATFS system. I think I've figured out what is potentially happening. Without using pointers, I am just overwriting the contents of my mainFileRef variable. But that still doesn't explain why the pointers didn't work.... maybe it was a build issue. Will retry

How are you checking mainFileRef? Do you check where it points, or the address of the variable itself (i.e. do you check the value of mainFileRef itself, or &mainFileRef)?

@Someprogrammerdude do you mean how am I checking the address? If so, I am checking via the debugger window watch variables. The file pointers are static global variables in the .c file.

Seems that you are confusing "the value of a variable" and the "address of a variable".... The address of a variable does not change. It's only the value that can change. Your pointer version is correct. After doing mainFileRef = &fileA then *mainFileRef is the same as fileA. BUT the address of mainFileRef is the same all the time.

BTW: Maybe the first approach will also work fine. It depends on the type FIL. If that type allows for simple assignment using =, the first approach will also work. Again - the value will change but the address will not.

I doubt you will need to copy the FIL as the FatFS library functions expect a FIL *.
